# Shopify button not working

Tags: html, shopify, form-submit

I am having a problem getting the add to cart button to work. Not sure, what portion of code is causing this problem. However, is the link with the issue: https://barkerbespoke.com/collections/tie-collection/products/black-wool

What do you suggest?

Comment: add cart works fine `tested on latest chrome: 57`

Comment: Yet, it doesn't work on Safari, nor Internet explorer.

Comment: works on Safari `10.0.2`

Comment: Perhaps it's just Safari 10.1?

Comment: `IE11` also works - just checked.

Comment: Then just a issue in Safari 10.1. Are you saying it's just a browser issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143167/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-laurens-van-oorschot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On theme.scss.css find class .controlls and decrease z-index to 99 and add this css to this class:

```
.product-detail__utilities{position:relative; z-index:999;}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @LaurensVanOorschot why don't you Upvote if it solved your problem? Thats how we reward here!

Comment: Apologies, still new to Stackoverflow.